# Can't import "mysql2/promise" into ES module (MJS) on Node.js 13 / 14

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules, commonjs, es6-module-loader

While migrating from CommonJS (`.cjs`) to ES Modules (`.mjs`), I've faced an issue of importing namespaced CJS to MJS:

```js
import mysqlPromise from "mysql2/promise";
```

returns an error:

> Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module
> 'C:\Users\User\IdeaProjects\…\node_modules\mysql2\promise' imported
> from…

I checked checked the relevant thread [ES Module support? Node 13](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/issues/1093), but don't see a clear solution.

Is there any way to import a namespaced CJS to ES Module/MJS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using:

```js
import mysqlPromise from "mysql2/promise.js";
```