# Node+ExpressRouter -> CommonJS to ESM --> Import routes --> Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module

Tags: node.js, migration, express-router, es6-modules

I cant find my mistake after updating the node engine to 14.x and using ESM instead of CommonJS: exampleroute.js

```
import express from "express";
const router = express.Router();
router.get("/exampleroute", async (req, res) => {
  console.log('......')
})
export default router;
```

server.js

```
import http from "http";
import express from "express";
import exampleroute from "./routes/exampleroute";
const server = express();
server.use("/exampleroute", exampleroute);
const httpServer = http.createServer(server);
const httpPort = 8080
httpServer.listen(httpPort, () => console.log(`server is running @ port: ${httpPort}`));
```

Leads to: **Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module**

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```js
import exampleroute from "./routes/exampleroute.js";
```

ref.
[Can't import "mysql2/promise" into ES module (MJS) on Node.js 13 / 14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60903616/cant-import-mysql2-promise-into-es-module-mjs-on-node-js-13-14)